# How to set default image, if image is not available in php

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am having a code to show images, but if no image available need to show default image

Currently, I am having this code

```
<?php ?>
<img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID); ?>"/>  
<?php ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`has_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_post_thumbnail/) method to check the post have thumbnail and based on that provide default image.

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
<img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID); ?>"/>  
<?php else: ?>
   <!-- default image here -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

---

You can use ternary operator to reduce the code.

```
<img src="<?php echo (has_post_thumbnail() ? get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID) : 'default_image.jpg'); ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
if (file_exists('current_file_path')) {
  <img src="current_file_path"/> 
}else{
  <img src="path_to_default_image"/> 
}
```